# computing convex hull by quick hull algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I am learning computational geometry and just started learning the topic of quick hull algorithm for computing convex hull. I have a question, if I want to 
draw a set of 2D points (say 10 points) for which the algorithm will have the worst case time complexity, how will I do this? is there any easy way to find out what the points would be?

The pseudocode Of the quick hull algorithm can be found [here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Hang/quick_hull/Algorithm.html)

Comment: What has your research turned up? Surely your examination of the steps of the algorithm have given you *some* clues. Why don't you post the pseudocode you're studying and your preliminary conclusions?

Comment: here is the pseudocode  I am following : @beaker
http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Hang/quick_hull/Algorithm.html

Comment: 10 points is way too low for a worst case to make sense. By the way, for a fixed number of points, all algorithms have exactly the same complexity O(1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the worst case of QuickHull is when no rejection ever occurs, i.e. when the given points form a convex polygon, and when the partitions are the most imbalanced.

So you can take points along a circle, at angles decreasing geometrically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a set of points that can generate worst-case time complexity behavior depends on the specific pseudocode you are given in the material you are studying.

The worst case complexity of Quickhull is **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**, and the average case performance is **O(NlogN)**. As you may have seen, Quickhull follows a divide-and-conquer strategy. Thus, achieving the latter(i.e. better) time complexity depends on being able to divide the problem into 2 similar sized (ideally equal) subproblems. If the dividing step is not balanced, and the number of elements in the 2 subproblems differ greatly, the algorithm will have to recurse N times. In other words, in each recursive step, the problem size will be reduced by a constant amount, instead of being reduced to a fraction of the original problem size.

Now, the pseudocode you provided takes the points with the lowest and highest X coordinates(i.e. leftmost and rightmost points) as bounds to divide the space into two. Ideally, this should divide the points into 2 equally large sets. But, what if this method is rendered inefficient by the specific points given as input? Then, at each step you would possibly exclude only a constant amount of points, say `c`, and the other half would still include `N-c` points. Consequently, the problem would have to recurse down **O(N)** steps and would end up with a quadratic complexity.

One such example, I believe, would be drawing a V shape with the points, as given below.

```
(0, 5)
(10, 5)
(1, 4)
(9, 4)
(2, 3)
(8, 3)
(3, 2)
(7, 2)
(4, 1)
(6, 1)
(5, 0)
```

Comment: would all the points on a circle fall in the worst case? @ilim

Comment: @user5411115 If you are talking about **all** the points on a circle, then yes. (just lower half or upper half of the circle would suffice, as well) But if you are referring to a specific set of points on a circle, then they trigger worst-case behavior would depend on the specific set of points. As you too may observe, the V shape example I gave in my answer was just a discrete version of the points on a half circle.